# WebView ProgressDialog + Timeout. Диалог загрузки + время ожидания ответа от сервера

Tags: java, android, webview, timeout

Решение для вставки диалога загрузки от пользователя: *yubaraj poudel*.
Слегка модифицирован под свои нужды.
Сокращение времени ожидания ответа от сервера.

```
public class NewsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webView;
    ProgressDialog prDialog;
    boolean pageFinished = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.page_news);
        setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv_news);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        String url = "http://google.com/";
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

            // Запуск диалога загрузки
            if (prDialog == null) {
                prDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewsActivity.this);
                prDialog.setMessage("Please wait ...");
                prDialog.show();
            }

        pageFinished = false;

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

         // Остановка загрузки ресурса после задержки и вызов метода toast
         // c сообщением об ошибке если страница не окончила загрузку
                        if (!pageFinished) {
                            mWeb.stopLoading();
                            myToast();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 10000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            // Останавливаем прогресс-диалог
            if (prDialog != null) {
            prDialog.dismiss();
            prDialog = null;
            pageFinished = true;
        }

        }
    }

// myToast
public void myToast() {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Ошибка: Адрес недоступен или отсутствует интернет соединение", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
    toast.show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можете сделать свою реализацию, к примеру:

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    boolean timeout;

    public MyWebViewClient() {
        timeout = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        ...
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(timeout) {
                    // Вот теперь ошибка.
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        ...
        timeout = false;
    }
}
```

Можете использовать `Timer`, `Handler`, что посчитаете правильнее.

Comment: Я пока новичок в программировании. Предоставленный код ошибок не вызывает, однако и результата срабатывания не вижу. Спустя 10 сек ничего не произошло (должен был выдать toast с текстом) и ожидание загрузки длилось дальше около 30 секунд, пока по дефолту не выдало ответ: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: А Вы правильно в `if(timeout)` обрабатываете необходимые действия?

Comment: Вчера ковырялся с дебагером, toast напрямую нельзя использовать.
Выдает ошибку `"Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()"`

Comment: В принципе нашел информацию по поводу `Timer`, отрабатывает нормально. Однако помимо самого таймера и события по истечению времени, мне нужен метод, который позволит отменить текущую загрузку URL страницы. Ибо после отработки таймера, спустя время (около 60 секунд) выдает ошибку `net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`. Каким образом остановить процесс загрузки?

Comment: @VictorIT, `.stopLoading()`

Comment: спасибо за помощь. Вопрос решен и отредактирован под готовый код.